# Will apps built for iOS 6 or earlier versions run without issues on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7

Or does every app producer need to make updates to their app to make them run on iOS 7. I assume not, but I'd love a confirmation and some risks that are present in apps built for earlier versions of iOS when running on iOS 7.

Comment: As always, the answer is "maybe".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes up every year. This is not specific to iOS 7 (or any other version of iOS).

As a developer you must test your existing app(s) to be sure they will work as-is under the upcoming version of iOS. Some apps will work just fine with no changes. Many apps will have some issue ranging from a small UI glitch to frequent crashes.

You need to install the beta iOS on a test device and test your app from the app store and see what issues you have, if any.

If you find any issues you then need to fins solutions. In many cases you can fix your app without the need to update to the latest Base SDK. But in some cases you may want to update to the latest and use some new features while fixing any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to test:

- built on iOS 6, run on iOS 7 (likely to work, possible minor appearance issues)
- coded against iOS 6, built on iOS 7, run on iOS 7 (likely to need work)
- coded against iOS 7, built on iOS 7, run on iOS 6 (likely to need lots of work)

YMMV

Comment: How do you do "built on ios6, run on ios7"?

Comment: You'll need to use a copy of XCode 4.6 - you can save one aside into a different folder (not Applications) before you upgrade.  Create an ad-hoc signed app to install on the iOS 7 device.

Answer (score 2):

Unless some of the functions/features you are using are 100% deprecated from the previous versions of iOS SDK you should be fine. If it is something newly deprecated, Apple gives you a few versions to use the older methods before you have to update. Generally speaking all of your iOS 6 apps should work fine in iOS 7. Lots of the the aesthetics in iOS 7 will require some style tweaking such as the borderless buttons, and some color styles.

Your best bet is eventually to maintain the look and feel of the apple ecosystem, and abide by apple's ios7 guideline.

But to answer your question, your app will run, but may risk looking antiquated.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html

(you may need an apple ID/dev account to access the link above)

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess would be that apps made for iOS 5 and later will run on iOS 7, as that was a major turning point in terms of the internal architecture of the Cocoa Touch framework, though this is still too soon to tell. It depends on the architecture of the device (whether the device was made for iOS 4/5/6/7), as well as how many OS-specific method calls for each particular version you use, and how well those methods migration is supported by the Apple team...

Answer (score 0):

From our experience, you MUST re-test everything, and decide how you handle new limitations.
For example - there's a new privacy permission for using the microphone, that you can't handle in iOS6-based apps that run on iOS7. 
Another important issue is running your app on older devices (iPhone 4 namely) with iOS7. We had lots of stuff going on in `[application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` and in iOS 7 we start getting crashes since it took much longer for this code to run, and the iOS kills apps that run this method more than 10 seconds. So, we had to revise our code, even though it wasn't related to any specific SDK changes.

Anyway, I know it's hard and time consuming but you can never tell what impact a new iOS can have on your app, so to be on the safe side - you should at least re-test all major functionality. And seriously consider migrating to iOS7 altogether, if it's possible before the market release of the new OS.